# jquery: live querying of selectors not working in ie6, ie7

Tags: jquery

I have my code snippet like this...

```
$('#ShowRatings a.show').click(function() {
    $('#contents').html('#some_div');
    createGraph($('#contents .ratings-contents'));
});
```

My problem is that the click trigger (`'#ShowRatings a.show'`) I am using does not change when the page loads, but the selector which is used in function `createGraph()` is changing - I am manipulating the jquery dom. So, in IE6/IE7, it shows an error like `object not found`. In other browsers this snippet works fine.

If it would have been an event trigger that would have been manipulated using jquery, I would have `live` event, but how can I handle the selectors that are changing?

Comment: Maybe I am just dummy, but I didn't understand "selectors that are changing" ? What is changing?

Comment: @Tx3 - I meant to say that the manipulating the dom using jquery on click event. So, `#contents` which is empty on page load, gets `.ratings-contents` as a child element on click event of a link `#ShowRatings a.show`. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have this code in `$(document).ready(function(){ your code; });`?

If you use `live` it should be ok.

Divs you want select are not changing (if you don't manipulate html code via javascript or jquery). In my opinion your code is before the html code, so it is triggered before DOM is loaded. In FF it could work, because it is so fast that DOM is created before `click` is defined. Inside `click` function it works always, because every time  you call `click` jQuery makes new search in DOM elements. So please use [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) I mentioned.

**edit:**

Do:

```
$('#ShowRatings a.show').live('click',function() {
    $('#contents').html('#some_div');
    createGraph($('#contents .ratings-contents'));
});
```

Comment: My code is indeed before the html but the code that I mentioned above is inside `$(document).ready`.

Comment: the said selectors do not get added/manipulated on page load, they get added on a `click` event, so as you mentioned, the IE6/IE7 do not do a fresh dom search that's why its not working. That's my problem, how can I solve it?